# Add more field on WordPress media upload

Tags: uploads

Using WP drag/drop upload, the request payload (via Chrome DevTools) as below :

```
------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

butterfly.jpg
------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action"

upload-attachment
------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_wpnonce"

abc123
------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="async-upload"; filename="butterfly.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundary--
```

Is it possible to add more field to this? without using plugins?

Answer (score 0):

not without creating your own custom form.  There are 2 ways to achieve this,

1. **uploading attachments in the post editor**, In your post edit page you can create a custom [metabox](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/) which will allow you to enter custom fields for your posts.  When you save your post, you can hook into the backend saving process using the [save_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) action and look for your custom fields in the [$_POST](http://form.guide/php-form/php-form-post.html) array of submitted fields.  You can also capture the attachment id in case you want to attach your custom fields to the attachment itself.
2. **Creating a custom admin page with am uploader**, alternatively you can create a custom admin page and setup your own attachment uploader and custom fields.  See this little video [tutorial](https://www.grafikart.fr/tutoriels/wordpress/wp-media-uploader-403) for more details.